# Subtracting a number from the names of all the files in a directory

Tags: bash

In a directory, I have the following files

```
0069.png  0074.png  0079.jpg  0084.png
```

and more of similar named files.

How can I change their names by subtracting a number from their names,  in bash?

For example, after subtracting 17, the files above would be

```
0052.png  0057.png  0062.jpg  0067.png
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below rename command on the directory where the jpg and png files you want to rename are located.

```
$ rename 's/^0*\K(\d+)/$1-17/e' *.* -vn
0069.png renamed as 0052.png
```

From `man rename`,

```
-v, --verbose
           Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.

-n, --no-act
           No Action: show what files would have been renamed.
```

Remove `-vn` from the above command to do the renaming. `e` modifier allows expressions to be evaluated in the replacement part.

Add `-f` option to do a force renaming.

```
rename 's/^0*\K(\d+)/$1-17/e' *.* -f
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls
1.jpg  2.png
$ rename 's/^0*\K(\d+)/$1+1/e' *.* -fvn
1.jpg renamed as 2.jpg
2.png renamed as 3.png
```

Comment: What are you running `rename` on. There is no `-n` option in `rename from util-linux 2.23.2`??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin n means no-act. It just displays how the output would be.

Comment: The `rename` from util-linux only supports `-v verbose`, `-s symlink` on LInux (help and Version are also available). Are you on Linux?

Comment: Yep, i'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks. What if renaming will overwrite an existing file? For example, I think the files will be renamed in the increasing order of their names, so if add a number to all the files' names,  that may overwrite existing files

Comment: What does `rename --version` tell you on Ubuntu? On Archlinux and openSuSE, neither support that option. Something is fishy. I like the solution, but it looks like we have different renames. Where does your rename come from?

Comment: @Tim renaming will renames the existing files. It won't change the file contents. I don't know what behavior you want.

Comment: If I have `1.png` and `2.png`, and I add `1` to their names for creating `2.png` and `3.png`, will renaiming `1.png` to `2.png` overwrite the existing `2.png`?

Comment: According to `man rename` that I have, you would not want to do that. It says **WARNING The renaming has no safeguards.  If the user has permission to rewrite file names, the command will perform the  action without any questions.** You are probably better off renaming (copying) into a new directory (say: `./new`) if there is any question about overwriting. (**that is in addition to the backup you have already made -- right?**)

Comment: @Tim no, it won't rename `1.png` to `2.png` if `2.png` is already exists.

Comment: But I want `2.png` to be `3.png` and `1.png` to be `2.png`. How?

Comment: your update has `2.png` and `1.jpg`, which will have no overwriting because their ext names are different. `-f` is to force overwriting, not avoid overwriting.

Comment: @Tim i didn't get you.

Comment: Thanks, @Avinash. (1) If you have `1.png` and `2.png` in a directory, and add `1` to their names by `rename 's/^0*\K(\d+)/$1+1/e' *.* -f`,  you will have only one `3.png` in the directory, because the command first rename `1.png` to `2.png` so the original `2.png` will be overwritten, and then rename the new `2.png` to `3.png` ending up only `3.png` in the current directory. How can i get `2.png` and `3.png` (by renaming the original `1.png` and `2.png` resp.) instead?   (2) When subtracting `2` from the name of `0100.png`, the filename will become `098.png`. How can we get `0098.png` instead?